# How do i send this form and store the JSON as a var

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

i want to send this form to the API after the user inputs the authorization code. I know i need to intercept the submit with JS or send the form as an AJAX post. I've included my attempts to do this but i can't get them to work. A response looks like this:

```
{"access_token":"mfi2s6i41i8hannfkaa3l87rbt","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":57600}
```

I want to save the respons as 3 seperate var's but for most the `access_token`

html:

```html
  <body>
    <!--   form for authentication   -->
    <form id="auth-form" action="https://rsgdeborgen.zportal.nl/api/v3/oauth/token" method="post">
    <!--   hidden post data      -->
    <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code"/>
    <!--    user inputfield || user input = 12 number long authorization code from: https://rsgdeborgen.zportal.nl -->
    <input id="user-auth-input" name="code" type="text" placeholder="Koppelcode" minlength=12 maxlength=15 required autofocus/>
    <!--    post button    -->
    <button id="post-button" value="inloggen" onclick="change()">inloggen</button>
  </form>
  <div id="display">
    
  </div>
  <!--   link to javascript   -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Attempt for AJAX

```js
function sendData(callback) 
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://rsgdeborgen.zportal.nl/api/v3/oauth/token';
    var params = 'code=' + document.getElementById('user-auth-input').value;
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);

    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            var response = xhttp.responseText, js;
            try
            {
              js = JSON.parse(response);
              if(typeof callback === 'function') callback(js);
            }
            catch (e)
            {
              if(typeof callback === 'function') callback(null);
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.send(params);
}

function useToken(obj)
{
  if(obj) console.log("Token = " + obj.access_token);
}

sendData(useToken);
```

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/53N71N3L/pen/jpMbJe/%22link%20to%20codepen%22)

Answer (score 0):

Server responds with code 500, because the `grant_type` is missing.

Comment: thx for the respons, I tryed it like this: var body = {
    grant_type: 'authorization-code';
    authorization-code: document.getElementById("user-auth-input");
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://rsgeborgen.zportal.nl/api/v3/oauth/token',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: body,
    complete: function(result) {
        //called when complete
        alert(result);
    },

    success: function(result) {
        //called when successful
        alert(result);
    },

    error: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    },
});

Comment: Thats the HTML ^^